# C# - MySQL - Get value from column if status is 'a'

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm trying to get a value from `123` if the `status` is `a`/
This is what my table looks like

```
|123|status|
|dsg|a     |
|ert|b     |
|abc|a     |
```

So, I only want to get `dsg` and `abc`, because there `status` is `a`.

But how can I do this in C#?

This is my current code:

```
public string getAll() {
    command6 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT 123 FROM table1 WHERE status= ?status", connection);
    command6.Prepare();

    command6.Parameters.AddWithValue("?status", "a");
    command6.ExecuteNonQuery();


    return command6.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

But this only returns `dsg`, not `dsg` and `abc` :(

- Bram

Comment: `ExecuteScalar()` returns the first column of the first row in the result set.

Comment: @Ullas , just .ToString() doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using ExecuteScalar which return only first record and ignore others as msdn say:

> [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Executes the query, and returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

You need to use:

```
MySqlDataReader dr = command6.ExecuteReader();
List<string> data=new List<string>();
while (dr.Read())
{
    data.Add(dr["123"].ToString());        
}
```

Comment: This worked for me, but the code you send is really poor. Second line of the code you miss a `;` and `add` is with a Capital. I'm talking about MySQL, so you need a `MySqlDataReader`, not a `SqlDataReader`

Comment: glad it works for you, actually I have coded directly here in SO editor, intellisense make us lazy :)

Answer (score 1):

You get only one value because you're using `ExecuteScalar()` method which is used to return one value only (in your case the value of the first record returned).

You need to use a reader to return multiple values:

```
 MySqlDataReader reader = command6.ExecuteReader();
 while(reader.Read())
 {
     String value = reader.GetString(0); // do something with it, e.g. put into a list
 }
```

You need to also change the output type of your function `getAll()` to return multiple string values (e.g. an array or list) or concatenate all the values from the database into one string.